# Setting linear-gradient with JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, gradient

I tried setting the background of an element with JavaScript like:

```
var someVar = 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #60aaff 0%,#2989d8 42%,#207cca 49%,#0a99c9 57%,#7db9e8 71%,#7f4e16 72%,#7a3522 100%)'
//....
element.style.background = someVar;
```

This happens multiple times with multiple different gradients.

In Chrome, it works fine. In Firefox, I get weird overlaying of the old gradient and the new.

[image: two gradients overlayed]

When I check in the Dev Tools, I see the browser has set the background as

```
<body id="app-body" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, rgb(96, 170, 255)...
```

Adding the `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` before the gradient.

After some time or if I open and close* the browser window, it seems to display correctly. (I tried using `-moz-linear-gradient` and got the same results).

I assume this is a Firefox issue, not a coding issue. But my question is: Is there a work around? Some other way to procedurally set the background that may force the browser to do it correctly without waiting a bit.

Edit: * By this I mean minimize and expand.

Comment: share full code so we can test

Comment: I don't have firefox installed right now so I'm just taking a guess on this: `background` is the combination of `background-color`, `background-image` and lots of other stuff. Maybe firefox is filling those for you. Try setting `background-image` instead of `background`: `element.style.backgroundImage = someVar;`